# Generating dummy variable

Tags: conditional-statements, stata

I have a problem with Stata.

I have two variables: `country` & `country_birthplace`

for example:

| country | country_birthplace | dummy variable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | US | 0 |
| India | India | 1 |
| India | US | 1 |
| US | (missing value) | . (missing value) |

I want to create a dummy variable that is 0 if both `country` and `country_birthplace` are `"US"`; 1 in all other cases; except where there is a missing value in `country_birthplace`, when I want a missing value.

I tried this code:

```
experience_abroad = cond(missing(country_birthplace), ., (country == "US" & country_birthplace == "US" ? 0 : 1))
```

But this gives me the dummy variable the other way around. So I get 1 for `US` & `US` and 0 in all other cases.

How can I get the output I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised at the implication that your code was accepted as legal.

It is utterly illegal:

1. You need `generate` or any abbreviation thereof.
2. The `x ? a : b` syntax is allowed in Mata but not in Stata.

```
gen experience_abroad = cond(missing(country_birthplace), ., !(country == "US" & country_birthplace == "US")
```

should work, as should

```
gen experience_abroad = !(country == "US" & country_birthplace == "US") if !missing(country_birthplace)
```

or

```
gen experience_abroad = cond(country == "US" & country_birthplace == "US", 0, 1) if !missing(country_birthplace)
```